# Using Dapper by stored procedure

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, asp.net-core, dapper

I am working on asp.net core by using dapper ORM.I want to execute stored procedure in dapper and get the result in boolean value.How i can achieve this?

Actually, In stored procedure , i am returning 0 or 1,but when response come back in code, then the result have -1, i am confused, i am returning just 0 or 1.

```
 using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    // Create User Connection
                    var queryParameters1 = new DynamicParameters();
                    queryParameters1.Add("@ConnectionId", connectionId);
                    queryParameters1.Add("@UserTokenId", tokenResult?.Id);
                    response = await connection.ExecuteAsync(
                        "Proc_CreateUserConnection",
                        queryParameters1,
                        commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
                }
```

I want to get the stored procedure output in boolean value or in the form of 0 or 1.

Comment: Try changing `ExecuteAsync(..)` to `ExecuteScalarAsync<bool>(...)`

Comment: How do you return the result from the stored procedure, with a `return` statement or by using a `select`?

Comment: Drik, I am using select statement in stored procedure

Comment: @Ali in this case the `ExecuteScalarAsync` method proposed in the answers will work. For return values this works a bit different (using a parameter with `ParameterDirection.ReturnValue`)

Comment: The point ultimately here is that the result of `ExecuteAsync` is the same as the result of `DbCommand.ExecuteNonQueryAsync` - and the integer result of that is **not** anything to do with anything you `select` or `return` - it is a separate thing. If you want to `select` a result, you're closer to `DbCommand.ExecuteScalarAsync`, which dapper makes available via an extension method of the same name

Comment: Thanks Simply Ged, Drik, Marc Gravell, ExecuteScalarAsync<bool>() This is working for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would just like to expand on this a little.

In this instance, you are returning a bool value which means its a single result. The best way to capture single results is using a scalar. This will ensure that only one value is returned and accessible by our code (as Deepankshee and others have already mentioned).

You should ensure that you issue a select command which will only ever return one result (otherwise it will fail) at the end of your stored procedure.

Then in your c# code you need to call:

```
var result = await conn.ExecuteScalarAsync<T>("Your procedure", new { arguments },
    commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
```

Please note as well that you should `await` on this so we don't block the thread.

Answer (score 2):

you can use ExecuteScalarAsync() instead of ExecuteAsync().Because it return a single value. when you will use select statement in SP

hope this works